# Endpoint requires authentication Rest API Spray

Tags: scala, spray

I would like to consume some resources from [This Rest API](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/commerce/transactions)
But it seems that I need some Authorization. And actually as a beginner I don't know how to access to this endpoint using Spray.

A simple example of Spray Client:

```
val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[GuildwarsApiResult]

  val responseFuture = pipeline {
    Get("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/46741")
  }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of questions lately from people who want to use API of GuilWars. Was it recently created ?

As per your question you need to specify HTTP header with API token as stated in [documentation](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:API_key) for POST requests. For GET requests you should pass token in URL.

[This](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/http/common/http-model.html#custom-headers) shows how to create and use custom http header.

```
object ApiTokenHeader extends ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion[ApiTokenHeader] {
  def renderInRequests = false
  def renderInResponses = false
  override val name = "Authorization"
  override def parse(value: String) = Try(new ApiTokenHeader(value))
}
final class ApiTokenHeader(token: String) extends ModeledCustomHeader[ApiTokenHeader] {
  def renderInRequests = false
  def renderInResponses = false
  override val companion = ApiTokenHeader
  override def value: String = "Bearer " + token
}
```

and use it as

```
val responseFuture = pipeline {
    Get("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/46741").withHeaders(ApiTokenHeader("55eec993e046c63bc8f486ee"))
  }
```

I didn't compile it but it should work.

Comment: For Bearer tokens, spray has `spray.http.OAuth2BearerToken` class 